# Declaring local variables

Tags: c#, syntax

Apologies in advance if the question is opinion based. Why would you pick the first variant of the following three, while declaring local variables in C#?

```
var list1 = new List();
List list2 = null;
```

```
var list1 = new List();
var list2 = (List)null;
```

```
// this variant would allow easy refactoring from class to struct 
var list1 = new List();
var list2 = default(List);
```

While this is impossible:

```
var list1 = new List(), list2 = null;
```

EDITED to provide the context:

```
void DoSomething(Action action) { /* ... */ }
// ..

var list1 = new List();
List list2 = null;
// ...
DoSomething(() => { list2 = new List(); list2.Add(1); });
```

Comment: Why would you declare a `null` variable in the first place? It depends entirely on context.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I'm not sure if that was exactly a question, but if it was--it's common to declare a variable null when you need to declare it in one scope and then fill the initial value in a different scope (such as declare outside try/catch and then assign inside the try).

Comment: If you're asking if there's any specific logical reason why you should pick the first form over the others in that specific case, the answer is 'no, there isn't'. They are functionally equivalent. I'd probably favour version 1 myself - the declaration is cleaner, no explicit casting needed. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Hence dependent on context. It's also common in a `TryXXX` scenario.. but I can't think of all that many other than the few like that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I provided the context.

Comment: Where is list2 in your edit? ...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, oops, it meant to be `list2` not `list1`, corrected.

Comment: It is still very unclear what you are trying to get in this question (outside of completely off-topic voting on personal preferences).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I see one advantage of using `var list2 = default(List)` form: easy refactoring. I don't see any advantages for other forms, so I asked this question to see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I don't see your comment about "ease of refactoring class to struct" as one that makes noticeable difference between the cases - changing frequently used class to be struct will require large effort anyway (i.e. due to changes in copy behavior), updating generic method from accepting class only to class+struct should not require a lot of work due to size... Cost of changing explicit to implicit type is almost 0 due to R#... so pure personal preference from my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is shorter and some people prefer it over specifying the type explicitly. In the context of anonymous types, you don't have an option except to use `var`, such as in

```
var point = new { X = 1, Y = 2 }
```

`var` is only syntactic sugar though. Not specifying the type does not mean it's dynamic. It only means the compiler will infer the type from usage. In the end, the compiled code is the same.

Within our team, we have a standard to use `var` on the left side when the right side is one of the following:

1. New object construction
2. Cast
3. Anonymous

In all other cases our internal standard does not allow `var` because in other cases it may not be explicitly clear what the variable type is to the reader (even though the compiler knows). For example, if you have a statement like this:

```
var x = SomeMethod();
```

What is the type of `x`? The compiler knows because it knows what `SomeMethod()` returns. Do you remember off-hand? Do you remember for every method in your application? We find it more expressive to not use `var` in these cases.

For a `null` value, I would always specify the type. Casts and such seem like just an odd mechanism to allow you to use `var` when it really gains you nothing.

```
List list = null;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. The question isn't "why use `var`".. its "what usage of `var` is preferred when declaring a `null` variable".. which seems like a silly question in the first place.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, thanks, I actually submitted the start of it before I finished my whole answer. I addressed `null` in the end.

Comment: No problem. I disagree with your `SomeMethod` example though.. a simple mouse hover in Visual Studio tells you what you need to know. Assuming your methods are named appropriately, you wouldn't even have to hover to figure it out. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I updated the question, is it less silly now? I personally prefer `var list2 = default(List)`. With very little effort I could make `List` a `struct` later, if I want to.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, yes, it was a point of discussion when we agreed on our standards. I do believe not using var here makes code easier to read, but I certainly understand others that prefer to use var 'cause it's shorter.

Comment: @SamuelNeff, would it be logical then to do: `List list1 = new List();
List list2 = null;` without `var` at all?

Comment: @avo, no, definitely don't do that. In that case you're creating a list and then immediately overwriting the variable with null. No need to create a list first.

Answer (score 1):

In case 2, all that you're doing is telling the compiler that list is going to be a List type object, and it will be initialized to null. You could do that, but it's a roundabout way of declaring a variable as being of type List.

You would only want to use case 3 if you're dealing with generics. The point of it being that you may not know if the type is a reference type or a value type, var list = null is not a valid statement for value types. The default keyword will ensure that either null is set for reference types and 0 for value types.

Answer:

According to [MSDN Reference: Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or to a method group or an anonymous function.

Comment: You explained the facts we all already know, but you did not answer the question.